# Bounty progression bug

Tags: discussion, bug, bounty

In the past I have offered a bounty for my [question about Talmudic maps.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89402/jacob-obermeyer-and-talmudic-maps)

I started with 500. Recently I offered another bounty [i think it was 50 or 100]. 
 I’d like to offer another bounty, but I am only being offered the choice of 500. However, per regulatory standards the limit of reputation required doubles each time for each new bounty.

The bug seems to be that that since I previously already offered five hundred I never attained this possible for *doublage* (no relation).

Am I terribly mistaken or is this a bug-?-

Comment: When did you offer a second bounty? The [timeline](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/89402/timeline) only shows one bounty.

Comment: @Alex ah must’ve mistaken it for something else; either way I think the point is still evident if not stronger.

Comment: So what's your question then? Are you asking why the minimum is 500?

Comment: Yes why now is it at 500, did I miss my normal progression changes? @Alex

Comment: If you started at 500 and it doubles each time then it wouldn't go *below* 500.

Comment: I wasn’t aware I’d lose such privileges and that it’ works like that, I guess - is that how it *for sure* works?@Alex

Comment: Sure seems like it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127155/i-can-only-offer-a-500-rep-bounty

Comment: @Mods - should this be tagged status-bydesign?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you put a bounty on a same question, the amount has to be at least twice than your previous bounty, until it reaches the maximum amount of 500.

Example progression: 50 - 100 - 200 - 400 - 500 - 500 - ...

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> #### Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired? / Can I raise my bounty?
>
> [...]
>
> [...] If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, **you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep)**. This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

Comment: The question was ‘if I skipped straight to 500 why can’t I go back’

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel because you can't offer a lower amount after your first bounty on the same question.